# How to remove radiator pipe and value?

Tags: pipe, removal, radiator, steam

We just had central air installed and the contractor removed the radiators.  However, the pipe and valves are left over sticking out of the floor upstairs.  I tried using a plumber's wrench to at least get the valve off but it would not budge.  How can I remove them?  Keep in mind that the house was built in the 1930's and removing the whole pipe would involve an asbestos abatement.  I rather keep and encapsulate the holes after removing the ends of the pipe with plaster.

Comment: Any method you use is still likely to cause the pipe to vibrate. The vibration will disturb the asbestos so use caution.

Comment: I was thinking of at least sealing the space around the pipe from where it is coming out of the floor with expanding foam.  You think that can help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used a reciprocating saw with a metal blade to cut though my cast iron pipe.  It's $60 if you don't already have one, but they come in handy. You could also use a angle grinder with a metal blade, but that's louder, sparkier and smells more.

[image]